# MYSQL Error Code 1290 after changing secure_file_path

Tags: mysql

After changing the secure_file_priv path and trying to load a csv file I get this error:

Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

My settings and code are below:

```
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /root/site/temp/          |
+---------------------------+

LOAD DATA INFILE '/root/site/temp/groster.csv' 
INTO TABLE 181_roster 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(first, last, gender, grade);
```

I also tried setting secure-file-priv="" and I get the following code when doing that:

Error Code: 13. Can't get stat of '/temp/groster.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

My dir permissions are:
drwxr-xr-x

The file permissions are:
-rw-r--r--

Any help would be appreciated, I've searched everywhere online and the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) hasn't seemed to help.  I'm also using: Server version: 5.7.20 for what it's worth.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: try disabling the option using `secure_file_priv=''` in mysql conf file

Comment: I've tried using secure_file_priv='' without any luck